# How do I access the digital signature of an InfoPath form from a workflow created with SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, digital-signature

I would like to create a workflow with SharePoint Designer that will run whenever an item in an InfoPath form library is modified that will check to see if the form has been signed.

The form is a travel expense form.  It will be created by a user, reviewed by an administrative assistant, and then approved or disapproved by the office manager.  Only the office manager needs to sign the form.

Environment is MOSS2007.

Answer (score 0):

In the Workflow Designer (In SharePoint Designer 2007) you can select a condition **If Signature equals Yes**.  That should give you what you want.